# How to manage scrollbars as we want

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

In the website I am currently creating, I am using Angular 8 (not sure whether the component paradigm has an influence on my troubles with scrollbars).

Like most websites, I need to implement a scrollbar in case the data does not fit the screen. But as I added more and more components, I realized that the way I used scrollbars was confusing and I ended up not being able to implement the behaviour I wanted.

I looked on the Internet but most ressources explain how to customize scrollbars, which is not what I am looking for. The article explaining the few CSS overflow properties were not very useful as well, because I did not have what I wanted, even though I kind of have tried every possibility (at least most I could think of).

Do you have any piece of advice to manage scrollbars ? Good practices & so on.

Currently the behaviour I am trying to implement is the following :
I have a home component containing a navbar and a router-outlet. The navbar is actually overflowing (because of box-shadow and an icon).
The router-outlet contains (if on the right page) a sidebar on the left side which represent a list of emails, and the content on the right. I don't want a global scrolling because I would have a empty space above the sidebar (where the navbar should have been but is gone because of scroll). I would need a scroll for the sidebar, and a scroll for the content.

So if you have any ressource which could help me understand how to use these scrollbars and manage them elegantly, that would be super appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this [perfect-scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/perfect-scrollbar) which is used for Angular 8.